# Pass Laravel Controller Function in VueJS props

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-props, laravel-controller

Can someone help me how do I pass this function in Vue "props"?

```php
public function showBusinessIntelligenceModule($store_id = NULL) {

        $stores = Stores::findOrFail($store_id);

        $reportParams = array(
            'date_from' => date('Y-01-01') . " 00:00:00",
            'date_to' => date('Y-12-t') . " 23:59:59",
            'store_id' => $store_id,
            'sku' => ''
        );

        $dashboard_rules = DashboardManagement::select('role_id', 'is_visible')
            ->where('role_id', \Auth::user()->role_id)
            ->where('dashboard_id', 2)
            ->get();
        
        $latestBusinessReportFile = BusinessReportFiles::getLatestRecord($store_id);
        $businessReportDate = $latestBusinessReportFile ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($latestBusinessReportFile->created_at)) :  date('Y-m-d');
        $inventory_forecasts = DB::table('restock_inventories', $store_id)
            ->join('product', function($join){
                $join->on('restock_inventories.product_id', '=', 'product.id');
            })
            ->where('product.store_id', $store_id)
            ->where('product.sku_type', '!=', 'Old Inactive')
            ->where('restock_inventories.days_of_supply', '<', 14)
            ->select('product.sku', 'restock_inventories.days_of_supply')
            ->groupBy('product.sku')
            ->paginate(10);
        // print_r($inventory_reports);

        $data = [
            'active'            => 'store_dashboard',
            'active_view'       => 'bim',
            'content_visibility'=>$dashboard_rules[0]['is_visible'],
            'store_id'          => $store_id,
            'stores'            => $stores,
            'report_params'     => $reportParams,
            'latestBusinessReportDate' => $businessReportDate,
            'restock_inventories' => $inventory_forecasts
        ];

        return view('stores_dashboard.bim')->with($data);
    }
```

sorry I missed other part of the code. I am trying to get the latestBusinessReportDate from this code and pass it in vueJS props. in blade file, i am getting an actual date. but im not sure how to get it in vue. this is my vue file btw,

```php
<template>
    <Modal @close="doClose">
        <template v-slot:container class="notifications">
            <section class="card forecast-vue-modal-container">
                <header class="card-header">
                    <h2>Days of Supply as of {{ latestBusinessReportDate }}</h2>
                    <!-- <span class="custom-close fa fa-times" @click="doClose"></span> -->
                </header>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <th>SKU</th>
                            <th>DAYS OF SUPPLY</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for='(item, index) in data' :key='index'>
                                <th v-if="('SKU')">{{ item.sku }}</th>
                                <th v-if="('DAYS OF SUPPLY')">{{ item.days_of_supply }}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <footer class="card-footer">
                    <div class="btn-group ml-auto float-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-close" @click="doClose">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    <!--  -->
                </footer>
            </section>
        </template>
    </Modal>
</template>

<script>
import Modal from "../Reusable/Modal";

export default {
    components: {
        Modal,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            errors: {},
            name: '',
        };
    },

    props: {
        data: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
    },

    methods: {
        doClose() {
            this.errors = {};
            this.name = '';
            this.$emit('close');
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

this data appears in a modal.

Comment: send via api or master blade

Comment: Post vue code too

Comment: Via API is the normal way ?

Comment: @JaseelPV hi, i edited my codes. posted everything. haha